# Bake texture of particles cinema4d

Tags: path, texture, cinema4d

What i want is to have particles coming into the screen by rolling down the screen under the influence of gravity and Filling up the screen t,some particles have red color while others are grey the red coloured ones roll down and exactly form a text.,how to do this?any guidance

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a container for the particle sim which matches your camera frame / screen size... you'll also need to either convert your letters into a similar containing mesh or set a particle sim goal using the letter meshes - I am 100% certain there are video tuts on exactly this sort of approach to particle-based motion graphics in Cinema 4D.